# xpath: find attribute value from identifier in current element attribute

Tags: xpath

I have an XML structure that looks like this:

```
<document>
<body>
<section>
<title>something</title>
<subtitle>Something again</subtitle>
<section>
<p xml:id="1234">Some text</p>
</section>
</section>
<section>
<title>something2</title>
<subtitle>Something again2</subtitle>
<section>
<p xml:id="12345678">Some text2</p>
<p getelement="1234"></p>
</section>
</section>
</body>
</document>
```

I want to search for the attribut value defined in "getelement". I got this code from a friendly soule here:

```
//section[section/p[@xml:id=@getelement]]/subtitle
```

but it doesnt work and i cant use current() since it is not supported in Arbortext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing the attributes of the same element, but they are not. You have to find the `getelement`:

```
//section[section/p[@xml:id=//@getelement]]/subtitle
```

Also note that `xml:id` attributes cannot start with digits.